# I want to calculate gauge in android but the logic I created is not working. Any suggestion?

Tags: android, calculator, gauge

The code is below, I am trying to make a guage calculator when user enter in fields the calculation should perform according to user's input number, new variables should create and perform some calculation as mention below.

```
    package com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator.R.id.activity_main;
import static com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator.R.id.add;
import static com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator.R.id.guage1;
import static com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator.R.id.weight;
import static com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator.R.id.wrap_content;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText guage1, guage2, weight;
    Button addmore, calculate;
    int value1, value2, totalSum;
    float calculated, calculated2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        guage1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guage1);
        guage2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guage2);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        addmore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String num1 = guage1.getText().toString();
                String num2 = guage2.getText().toString();
                String wei = weight.getText().toString();
                int number1, number2, number3, weight;
                number1 = Integer.parseInt(num1); //int value in number1
                number2 = Integer.parseInt(num2); //int value in number2
                weight = Integer.parseInt(wei); //int value in weight

                //now calculations
                switch (number1) {
                    case 16:
                        value1 = 4096;
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        value1 = 3136;
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        value1 = 2304;
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        value1 = 1600;
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        value1 = 1296;
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        value1 = 1024;
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        value1 = 784;
                        break;
                    case 23:
                        value1 = 576;
                        break;
                    case 24:
                        value1 = 484;
                        break;
                    default:

                }

                switch (number2) {
                    case 16:
                        value2 = 4096;
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        value2 = 3136;
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        value2 = 2304;
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        value2 = 1600;
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        value2 = 1296;
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        value2 = 1024;
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        value2 = 784;
                        break;
                    case 23:
                        value2 = 576;
                        break;
                    case 24:
                        value2 = 484;
                        break;

                }
                //switch for number 2 ended

                totalSum = value1 + value2;
                calculated = value1 / totalSum * weight;
                calculated2 = value2 / totalSum * weight;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("calculated", calculated);
                i.putExtra("calculated2", calculated2);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

and second activity

```
package com.cyberthreats.activitylifetester.gueagecalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    float calculated, calculated2;
    int number3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        TextView r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        TextView r2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        float i = intent.getFloatExtra("calculated", calculated);
        float j = intent.getFloatExtra("calculated", calculated2);
        r.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        r2.setText(String.valueOf(j));

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? and what are you getting?

Comment: the output should be the weight of different gauges for example

i enter 21 if field 1 and 22 in field 2 and 5000 in filed 'weight' , so a new variable should be initialized with case of input in filed 1 , and 2 , than 

new Initialized variable divide with sum of both new initialized variables and multiply with number inputed in 'weight' field , the answer will be in floating point but need to convert it into nearest for 5 or 10s ,..... 

and m getting 0.0 as a result in next activity

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Or any kind of error?

Comment: no any error but resulting 0.0 only

Comment: This might not be the reason for your error, but you retrive "calculated" twice from the intent in the second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things you need to change.

First change the type of `value1, value2, totalSum;` to float i.e `float value1, value2, totalSum;`

In `Main2Activity.java`, edit to match this line

`float j = intent.getFloatExtra("calculated2", calculated2);`

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: one more help please :) can i use variables of first activity to second one?

Comment: No unless they are `static` and `public` or you have an instance of First Activity in second one

Comment: i want in second Activity Showing result as

the guage for <input in first activity> is <calculated>